# Print line only if found match of regex is between whitespace in Python

Tags: python

I have a file `data.txt`:

```
<tag,1>moon sunlightcream potato</tag>
<tag,2>dishes light jellybeans</tag>
```

and a python file `match.py`:

```
for LINE in open("data.txt"):
    STRING = "light"
    if STRING in LINE:
        print (LINE)
```

The output is:

```
<tag,1>moon sunlightcream potato</tag>

<tag,2>dishes light jellybeans</tag>
```

I want only:

```
dishes light jellybeans
```

How can I do that ?

The larger context is:

```
TAG = QUERY.split("&")[1]
LIST = []
for LINE in open(DATA):
    STRING = "<tag,"
    if STRING in LINE:
        if TAG in LINE:
            print LINE
```

So I can't so it seems do `" light "` ! Because `"light"` is a variable. So I can't do so it seems: `" light "`

the regex option was:

```
 import re

 def sub_list():
     TAG = "light"
     p_number = re.compile(r'<tag,.*,' + TAG + ',.*,>')
     for LINE in open(DATA):
         match = p_number.findall(LINE)
         if match:
             print LINE
```

But that doesn't help also.

But now it works with:

```
import re

TAG = "light"
for LINE in open(DATA):
    STRING = "<tag,"
    if STRING in LINE:
        if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(TAG), LINE):
            print (LINE)
```

Comment: do `if STRING in LINE.split()`:

Comment: @hiroprotagonist he just wants the line where `light` is a whole word, not a substring

Comment: *"So I can't so it seems do " light " !"* ??

Comment: Note that not all text matching is based on regular expressions. To use regular expressions in python you must include the `re` library. But you don't make use of this library in your question, and therefore the title is misleading.

Comment: A [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), regex or regexp, is, in theoretical computer science, a sequence of characters that define a search pattern. The term **regex** is used here, perfectly correct and not misleading, in that sence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regex as below, `\b` match the [word boundary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), it match only at the beginning or end of a word, so it wouldn't match `light` if its a substring

```
import re
LINES = ['moon sunlightcream potato', 'dishes light jellybeans']
match_tag = 'light'
for LINE in LINES:
  # you could also use re.search(r'\b' + match_tag + r'\b', LINE)
  if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(match_tag), LINE):
    print (LINE)
# only print 'dishes light jellybeans'
```

Comment: How does this work with a variable ? `TAG = "\b" + TAG + "\b"`

Comment: you are close, you could use `re.search(r'\b' + TAG + r'\b', LINE)`, check my updated answer

Comment: Aha, `my_regex = r"\b" + TAG + r"\b"` seems to work  in `if re.search(my_regex, LINE):`

Comment: What's the benefit of using `re.search` instead of `re.match` ? Would not that be slower?

Comment: `re.match` only match at the beginning of string, its equivalant to `re.search('^something')`, you can't use `re.match` for your case

Comment: Oh I see. I almost forgot about that